# How do I return a list of values from each iteration of a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iteration

I have a loop which is written to return values from a location in a list in a spreadsheet.
`daydataf` is the list of the dataframes I have created based on worksheets in the spreadsheet and `value_loc` is a list of tuples of the x,y coordinates of the value of the items I am looking for.
daydataf = [day_1, day_2, through day_15] of dataframes
value_loc = [(0,1), (1,2), (0,4)... 14 locations in the sheet of data I am trying to retrieve]

Current output is values for well name, company, hours worked
I would like to get a list with values of the elements for each day (i.e. day_1 = [well 1, bp, 60]
after each iteration.
Current output is a printout of well_vals that has well 1, bp, 60, well 2, bp, 80, etc

As I run this currently, it prints to the console a list of all values from all sheets. I would like to have it return a list of values after each iteration that I can use as a list to update a dataframe.

I am sure I am missing something easy but cannot figure it out!
I would like to have a `well_vals` list with the values of the items for each day printed after each iteration.

The code is as:

```
for day in daydataf:
    well_vals = []  # creates empty list for well values that will be located using loop

    for x,y in value_loc:  # looks at all paired tuples in value_loc list, one at a time
        well_val = day.iloc[x,y]  # locates cell in dataframe using x,y and assigns value
        well_vals.append(well_val)  # updates well_vals list with new value

        print(well_vals[-1])  # prints final copy of list, if not [-1] would print each
                              # iteration of list
```

Comment: I don't think you're using the word 'returns' correctly. Printing a value to console isn't the same as returning a value from a function.

Comment: write example of as your data and expected result you want

Comment: You are probably right. I am fairly new to python. What I would like is for the value that it prints to console each time to be stored to a list. I have edited my question accordingly - thanks for the help.

Comment: I have added sample data and the expected output. Input for the dataframe is an excel sheet which has data labels and values in random rows and columns (not tabular format, more a form)